# Can Liberty apps be deployed to WAS 8.0 also

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I'm interested in developing locally on Liberty profile 8.5.5 and WAS dev tools for Eclipse.

However, my company uses WAS 8.0.0.6.

Can Java EE artifacts developed for Liberty also be deployed to 8.0.0.6 without any xml changes or otherwise?

I guess both are Java EE 6 servers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the intent is to allow development on Liberty profile and deployment on the full profile.  There might be some system configuration differences, particularly around class loading, but you should be able to leave the application itself unchanged.